# I want to hide top content of webpage in webview

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I have webpage but I don't want navigation menu and search box. Can we float the webview container?

How to hide through android-webview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE); & mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Do not use INVISIBLE setting.